# Split text evenly and dynamically across page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to have something like this

```css
.full-width {
  font-size: 10vh;
  letter-spacing: 15vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  testing
</div>
```

and let's say that works, font is a nice size and is spread from one end to the other evenly. I made that css just by trying to see which size worked.

But if I change the text from 'testing' to something 'home', it wouldn't stretch across no more.

for example,

```css
.full-width {
  font-size: 10vh;
  letter-spacing: 15vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  home
</div>
```

Notice how home does not reach from end to end anymore, until I change the css (which again I discover from trail and error).

```css
.full-width {
  font-size: 10vh;
  letter-spacing: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  home
</div>
```

I'm not sure how I would dynamically change the text via js to predict the full needed width.

In regards to Yosef's answer; this is for a react component which I'm trying to pass new text towards in. So when I get into that situation `innerText` return's null so it causes me an error.

I tried approaching it like this

```
var footerContents = this.props.page();
 var contents = [];
 footerContents.split('').map(i => contents.push(<span> {i} </span>)).join('');
```

and then just display the contents

```
<div class="full-width">
  {contents}
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to accomplish. Is it so that the text always fill the entire width regardless of how long the text string itself is?

Comment: Yes, I've added a tad more detail in my question.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just CSS, you could us some JS to help http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for react case:

```
var footerContents = this.props.page() || '';
var contents = footerContents.split('').map(i => <span> {i} </span>);
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that for alternates to catching a null

Comment: in java-script the operator || will return the first value if its true-thy value, and the second if the first was falsy. similar for operator && - will return the first value if its falsy, and the second - if the first was true-thy

Answer (score 1):

it can be done with javascript:

```js
    var el = document.getElementById('test');
    var html = el.innerText.split('').map(i => '<span>'+i+'</span>').join('');
    el.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
        .full-width {
            font-size: 10vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

```html
<div id="test" class="full-width">
    home
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question regarding this answer. Although, it is what I was searching for.

Comment: just say `content = content || ''`. it will turn null to empty string and no will throw an error anymore

Comment: I'm slightly confused by where I would use that

Comment: when you get the content of the html. in the example above it's shuld look like : `var text = el.innerText || ''; var html = text.split('') ...`

Comment: i will ad an answer for react case